# Efficiency of PartialFunction orElse

Tags: scala

Is the use of a `PartialFunction`'s `orElse` more or less efficient than using a large `match` block during `apply` time?

To illustrate the question, is:

```
val pf = { case "a" => "A"} orElse 
         { case "b" => "B" } orElse 
         { case "c" => "C" } ...
```

more or less efficient than:

```
val pf = { case "a" => "A"
  case "b" => "B"
  case "c" => "C"
  ...
}
```

during application a value to `pf`:

```
pf(x)
```

Comment: Even if `orElse` is less efficient, it's probably not so inefficient to justify not using it when it can make your code cleaner. That being said, the example you give is contrived (which is fine, I'm not criticizing that): the latter example is preferred in that situation because there is no good reason to break those very similar cases up.

Answer (score 5):

See this [detailed analysis](http://code.technically.us/post/13107005975/or-else-its-rilly-complex) from the author of [unfiltered](http://unfiltered.databinder.net/Unfiltered.html). It's basically less efficient. I believe [some work](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/5fb26c6a889cf1609823338df8783bf880769b3f) has been done in trunk to address this, shortly after the blog post was made.

Answer (score 1):

The second case cannot possibly be less efficient than the first, because the compiler could just convert it into the first (and, in fact, that's not far from what the virtual pattern matcher does).

So, if you have the choice, the second case is always the safer bet.